# PHP-What exactly is Resource Id #4? What does it stand for?

Tags: php, mysql

What does Resource Id #4 stand for in php when you run this a script resembling this:

```
$dbs = mysql_connect('localhost', 'me', 'mypass') 
OR die('Couldn\'t connect to the database: '.mysql_error());
@mysql_select_db('my_db') OR 
die('Could not connect to the database: '.mysql_error());
$query_result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM mytable;");
```

Then echoing query_result? I know what you have to do

```
mysql_fetch_array($query_result);
```

to get the contents of said query's result, but I want to know what Resource Id #4 actually means.

Comment: It is what it says, a reference to a resource such as a mySql connection.

Comment: It's never bad for scripters to learn the basics of assembly and a C-language first. It will let you understand these principles much easier.

Comment: @Allendar From an academic perspective, sure, but the priority should be on getting things done if you're in a commercial environment with deadlines. "Sorry, I need to understand this at the machine level" is not going to fly if you're six weeks behind on your project.

Answer (score 1):

A resource is just a pointer to an external object; in this case, a database connection. More info is here: http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.resource.php

By the way, [do not use those functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php), ever. Presumably you've copied and pasted them from a site, but it's probably 13 years old.

Comment: Pointers will probably not make much sense if someone doesn't know what resource means ;). Guess it's a useful link tho :)

Answer (score 0):

I think you might be looking for this: http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.resource.php and this: http://www.php.net/manual/en/resource.php

You are echoing out the resource which is the result of `mysql_query` which is a special PHP varianble type.